# How can I paste files with the same name from different directories?

Tags: files, paste

I have another question.

I have three different directories but I have the same files inside, with the same name. For example:

Directory1:

```
dir1/file1.txt
dir1/file2.txt
dir1/file3.txt
```

Directory2:

```
dir2/file1.txt
dir2/file2.txt
dir2/file3.txt
```

Directory3:

```
dir3/file1.txt
dir3/file2.txt
dir3/file3.txt
```

I would like to paste the files with the same name. Like it:

`dir1/file1.txt` + `dir2/file1.txt` + `dir3/file1.txt` = `file1.txt`

`dir1/file2.txt` + `dir2/file2.txt` + `dir3/file2.txt` = `file2.txt`

`dir1/file3.txt` + `dir2/file3.txt` + `dir3/file3.txt` = `file3.txt`

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify what the `+` operator dose. Is it concatenation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to concatenate file content, then you can do this

```
cat dir*/file1 > file1
cat dir*/file2 > file2
cat dir*/file3 > file3
```

The wildcard will make the cat command read the content of all the dirs/files matching the pattern, thus you will get the content of files with the same name in all three directories written to the resulting file.

Comment: What about the order?

Comment: @phk The order is alphanumerical in the current locale.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only know the names of directories but not the names of the files you could save the file names from one of the directories in an array and then iterate over the elements, removing the directory name and pasting the resulting file name from each directory:

```
files=(dir3/*)
for p in "${files[@]}"; do 
f=${p#*/}; paste dir1/"$f" dir2/"$f" dir3/"$f" > "$f"; done
```

Note that it could be golfed shorter if a glob was used to have the shell expand it  (the directories names would then be used in lexicographical order) e.g.

```
for p in "${files[@]}"; do f=${p#*/}; paste dir*/"$f" > "$f"; done
```